# Xcode 11: Runtime breakpoint at libsystem_trace.dylib`os_log_fault_default_callback

Tags: ios, xcode, breakpoints

I implemented a number of UI tests for my app. They did run under Xcode 10 without problems.
After upgrading to Xcode 11, I am encountering a number of problems. The one that I was not able to solve up to now is that my tests stop at a breakpoint

```
libsystem_trace.dylib`os_log_fault_default_callback:
->  0x7fff5143cb3f <+0>: retq
```

in a `Thread 2 Queue : com.apple.dt.xctautomationsupport.snapshot-request (serial)`

This breakpoint is hit when I enable „All Runtime Issues“ breakpoints.
Any idea what is the reason, and how to avoid it?

EDIT:

I tried to delete this breakpoint with

```
(lldb) breakpoint delete 8.2
0 breakpoints deleted; 1 breakpoint locations disabled.
```

without success.

Answer (score 0):

just copy the program, close the project, make a new one , paste the program and run.
This happens because the previous program was compiled for xcode 10 or previous.
When you make a new project, it will be the settings for the 11 version.
so when you write a program, it will run!!